# Do not receive all prometheus alerts

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I'm currently trying to send custom alerts from my prometheus stack.

I installed prometheus using prometheus-community helm chart.
I also installed a mailhog to catch mail sent by alertmanager.

First, I created an alertmanagerconfig :

```
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: mailhog
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  receivers:
  - name: mailhog
    emailConfigs:
    - to: "test@fake.com"
      from: "cluster@fake.com"
      smarthost: "mailhog.mailhog.svc.cluster.local:1025"
      requireTLS: false
  route:
    groupBy:
    - severity
    groupInterval: 30s
    groupWait: 30s
    receiver: mailhog
    repeatInterval: 1m
```

That's work more or less because I receive some alerts configured by default when I installed prometheus chart.

However when I want to create my own custom alert it seems to be bugged :

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: prom-rule-test
  namespace: prometheus
  labels:
    release: prometheus
spec:
  groups:
    - name: ruleTest
      rules:
        - alert: test
          expr: vector(1)
          labels:
            severity: warning
```

I can see the rule in the prometheus web UI and I can see the alert in "FIRING" state. However, I do not receive anything in my mailhog.

I do not understand why. Any idea ?

EDIT :

@zer0 thanks for your answer, this is my prometheus resource :

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: prometheus
    project.cattle.io/namespaces: '["aws-ecr-helper","aws-efs","cattle-system","cert-manager","fluentd","ingress-nginx","kube-node-lease","kube-public","kube-system","prometheus"]'
  creationTimestamp: "2022-07-07T08:57:27Z"
  generation: 5
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 36.2.1
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack-36.2.1
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  namespace: prometheus
  resourceVersion: "225742469"
  uid: 68ce943f-95e4-4052-86f8-d095c4e0692b
spec:
  alerting:
    alertmanagers:
    - name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager
      namespace: prometheus
      pathPrefix: /
      port: http-web
  evaluationInterval: 30s
  externalUrl: http://myurl.com/
  image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.36.1
  logFormat: logfmt
  logLevel: info
  podMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
  podMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  portName: http-web
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: 1000Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 750Mi
  retention: 3d
  routePrefix: /
  ruleNamespaceSelector: {}
  ruleSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  rules:
    alert: {}
  scrapeInterval: 30s
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  version: v2.36.1
```

@Abdullah Barrak thanks for your answer. This is already done, I added the label `release: prometheus`

Comment: Can you show your `AlertManager` and `Prometheus` resources that you created? The `Prometheus` resource is the one that typically fires the alerts to the manager.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to add the needed labels for `PrometheusRule` to be picked up by `Prometheus`, along  with `ruleSelector:` as well in place: [Link](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/user-guides/alerting.md#rule-selection).

Comment: Hi @Abdullah Barrak, thanks for your answer. I already did that by adding ```release: prometheus```